# mongo - extract subdocuments field and convert to array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My query (**NOT AGGREGATION!**) using `findOne()` returns this kind of documents:

```
{
    "_id": "ddd00000000000000cb00001",
    "title": "Title",
    "questions": [
        { "_id": "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e23" },
        { "_id": "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e27" },
        { "_id": "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e2b" }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the questions _id directly into the array as strings, not subdocuments?
Desired result:

```
{
        "_id": "ddd00000000000000cb00001",
        "title": "Title",
        "questions": [
            "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e23", 
            "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e27",
            "60bfc1afcd3d6b68d44b1e2b"
        ]
}
```

I prefer to obtain my result without aggregation framework, but I'd like to see both solutions.
As far as I know, I can achieve the goal using $group and $push, but I'm looking for a more elegant move.

Answer (score 1):

Without aggregation, you would have to do it on the client side:

```
let doc = db.test.findOne({});
doc.questions = doc.questions.map(e=>e._id);
```

With aggregation, you can project the field:

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {$match:{}},
   {$limit:1},
   {$addFields:{questions:"$questions._id"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UU7tbuMskYG)